# lambda function don't closure the parameter in Python?

Tags: python, lambda

Code talks more:

```
from pprint import pprint

li = []

for i in range(5):
        li.append(lambda : pprint(i))

for k in li:
        k()
```

yield:

```
4
4
4
4
4
```

why not

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

??

Thanks.

P.S. If I write the complete decorator, it works as expected:

```
from pprint import pprint

li = []

#for i in range(5):
        #li.append(lambda : pprint(i))

def closure(i):
        def _func():
                pprint(i)
        return _func

for i in range(5):
        li.append(closure(i))

for k in li:
        k()
```

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2295290/195823) and [my answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python/2295372#2295372)

Comment: You can see that is is closing the variable by moving the original loop into a function, and then calling the function before the `for k in li:` line, so that `i` isn't a valid name in the module level scope. It will still work (and get the same result because it's closing a reference not the value), meaning that the name is closed.

Comment: Thank you all. I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python/2295368#2295368 tells not only the solution but also why. I think my question is duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture)

Answer (score 12):

you need to do:

```
lambda i=i: pprint(i)
```

instead to capture the current value of `i`

Answer (score 3):

It does properly reference `i`, only the thing is, that by the time your list gets populated, `i` would have the value assigned form the last item in the sequence when the iteration ended, so that's why your seeing `4` all over.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a default argument -- which could introduce bugs if accidentally called with an argument -- you can use a nested lambda:

```
from pprint import pprint

li = []

for i in range(5):
    li.append((lambda x: lambda: pprint(x))(i))

for k in li:
    k()
```

This is an anonymous version of your `closure` function.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda functions create closures over the `i` variable. After the first `for` loop is finished, `i` has value `4`.

Then the second `for` loop starts and all the lambda functions are executed. Each of them then prints the current value of `i`, which is `4`.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: Because the code inside the lambda is using your global variable `i`.

Your second variant will do the same as the first one with lambda if you remove the parameter `i`:

```
def closure():
```

Instead of

```
def closure(i):
```

I.e. the code inside the function will use the global variable `i`.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the scope of the variable, it's the fact that what is closed is a reference to a value rather than a value. See my comment to the question -- if you move the `for i in range` loop into a function, so `i` doesn't exist in global scope, then call the function before the `for k in li` loop, it will give the same answer.

Comment: >if you move the for i in range loop into a function, so i doesn't exist in global scope, then call the function before the for k in li loop, it will give the same answer... --- i.e. non local? That's what i meant.

Comment: it is looking for variable `i`. as there is no function argument `i` it takes variable `i` from outer scope.