# Creating lambda inside a loop

Tags: python

I am trying to create lambdas inside a loop that iterates over a list of objects:

```
lambdas_list = []
for obj in obj_list:
   lambdas_list.append(lambda : obj.some_var)
```

Now, if I iterate over the lambdas list and call them like this:

```
for f in lambdas_list:
    print(f())
```

I get the same value. That is the value of the last `obj` in `obj_list` since that was the last variable in the block of the list iterator. Any ideas for a good (pythonic) rewrite of the code to make it work?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python/2295372#2295372, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514093/lambda-function-dont-closure-the-parameter-in-python.

Comment: most descriptive answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-python-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters/938493#938493

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use this line instead:

```
lambdas_list.append(lambda obj=obj: obj.some_var)
```

Answer (score 24):

You either have to capture the variable using default assignments

> ```
> lambdas_list = [ lambda i=o: i.some_var for o in obj_list ]
> ```

or, use closures to capture the variable

> ```
> lambdas_list = [ (lambda a: lambda: a.some_var)(o) for o in obj_list ]
> ```

In both cases the key is to make sure each value in the obj_list list is assigned to a unique scope.

Your solution didn't work because the lexical variable `obj` is referenced from the parent scope (the `for`).

The default assignment worked because we reference `i` from the `lambda` scope.  We use the default assignment to make "passing" the variable implicit by making it part of the `lambda` definition and therefore its scope.

The closure solution works because the variable "passing" is explicit, into the outer `lambda` which is immediately executed, thus creating the binding during the list comprehension and and returning the inner `lambda` which references that binding.  So when the inner `lambda` actually executes it will be referencing the binding created in the outer `lambda` scope.

Answer (score 10):

You can do something like that:

```
def build_lambda(obj):
  return lambda : obj.some_var

lambdas_list = []
for obj in obj_list:
   lambdas_list.append(build_lambda(obj))
```