# How can I force Python to create a new variable / new scope inside a loop?

Tags: python, variables, for-loop, parameters, closures

Today I explored a *weird* behavior of Python. An example:

```
closures = []
for x in [1, 2, 3]:
    # store `x' in a "new" local variable
    var = x

    # store a closure which returns the value of `var'
    closures.append(lambda: var)

for c in closures:
    print(c())
```

The above code prints

```
3
3
3
```

But I want it to print

```
1
2
3
```

I explain this behavior for myself that `var` is always the same local variable (and python does not create a new one like in other languages). How can I fix the above code, so that each closure will return another value?

Comment: Hint: what introduces a new variable scope in Python?

Comment: just saw that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546285/creating-lambda-inside-a-loop?rq=1 is a duplicate question. how can I close this one or shall I delete it?

Comment: @tampis: Just vote to close – the moderators will eventually decide whether this question is merged or deleted.

Comment: Actually, I don't think that that even does what you think it does. Try adding `del var` after the first loop.

Comment: @cha0site `del var` gives the exception `lobal name 'var' is not defined`

Comment: @tampis: Exactly. Note that it throws that exception not on the `del var` line, but on the `print(c())` line. That is, the code didn't actually create a closure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use a default argument for your lambda, this way the current value of `x` is bound as the default argument of the function, instead of `var` being looked up in a containing scope on each call:

```
closures = []
for x in [1, 2, 3]:
    closures.append(lambda var=x: var)

for c in closures:
    print(c())
```

Alternatively you can create a closure (what you have is not a closure, since each function is created in the global scope):

```
make_closure = lambda var: lambda: var
closures = []
for x in [1, 2, 3]:
    closures.append(make_closure(x))

for c in closures:
    print(c())
```

`make_closure()` could also be written like this, which may make it more readable:

```
def make_closure(var):
    return lambda: var
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't create a new variable in the local scope inside the loop.  Whatever name you choose, your function will always be a closure over that name and use its most recent value.

The easiest way around this is to use a keyword argument:

```
closures = []
for x in [1, 2, 3]:
    closures.append(lambda var=x: var)
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that is okay for a +1 now.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, `var` is always bound to the the last value of the loop. You need to bind it inside the lambda using `closures.append(lambda var=var: var)`.