# Lambda in loop stored in list, prints only the last loops evaluated value not different values from all loop iterations

Tags: python, lambda

I have a problem with lambdas in a loop. It is hard to explain the problem so I will show it in a short example:

```
class TestObj():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

lambdas = []
values_list = [10, 1]
for ele in values_list:
    foo = TestObj(ele)
    lambdas.append(lambda: foo.value > 5)

print([single_lambda() for single_lambda in lambdas])
```

as a result of print I get:

```
[False, False]
```

Despite I would expect [True, False]. 
Could you tell me why it does not work? and how Could I get the result that I expected? I only add that lambdas in a loop are required in my code to define formulas(those formulas are a lot and can be much more complex). Those formulas are defined in one place in the application and executed after many lines below the definition.
I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: First of all, please  double check this: `self.value` in `__init__` should be `self.value = value`

Comment: oh sorry, my bad, I made mistake during creating the post, in my test code is self.value = value. I will correct it here also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lambdas are evaluated when they are executed.

They are executed when you print them. The only known *`foo`* at that time is the one from the last loop. So `TestObj(1)` is printed twice.

You can verify this by changing your lambda to:

```
lambdas.append(lambda: id(foo))   # will print the id() of the used foo
```

You need to "early" bind the `foo` from the loop to the lambda:

```
lambdas.append(lambda x = foo: x.value > 5) # bind x to foo from loop, check x.value
```

Full fix:

```
class TestObj():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

lambdas = []
values_list = [10, 1]
for ele in values_list:
    foo = TestObj(ele)
    # use an x and bind it to this loops foo
    lambdas.append(lambda x = foo: x.value > 5)

# this is bad btw, use a simple for loop - do not use a list comp to create a list
# simply to print values 
print([single_lambda() for single_lambda in lambdas])
```

Output:

```
[True, False]

# and for the changed lambda with id() : the same id() twice
```

---

See [Is it Pythonic to use list comprehensions for just side effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects) regarding using list comprehension sideeffects and why its bad.

---

Related:

- [Unexpected behaviour with a conditional generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54245618/unexpected-behaviour-with-a-conditional-generator-expression/54249614#54249614)

Comment: Nice. Really useful post, thanks. I for one hadn't come across early binding with lambdas, hence the class workaround (see my other answer). I wonder why this is not more widely known and used.

Comment: @ala this comes up 1-2 a month - mostly in combination with TK gui's - when binding functions to buttons - unfortunately can't find a good dupe and those posts are full of TK-related code. :) I am pretty sure someone with better google foo might be able to locate a dupe.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `foo` is merely lexically defined in the lambda, so it is not storing the value of `foo` from the time when the lambda was created.

Instead of a lambda, you could perhaps use a class to generate your callable.  This can then store the associated state, namely the `TestObj` instance to which `foo` was pointing:

```
class TestObj():
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class MyFunc():
    def __init__(self, testobj):
        self.testobj = testobj

    def __call__(self):
        return self.testobj.value > 5


funcs = []
values_list = [10, 1]
for ele in values_list:
    foo = TestObj(ele)
    funcs.append(MyFunc(foo))

print([single_func() for single_func in funcs])
```

output:

```
[True, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

For what you're doing you can use a `map` function. Small example:

```py
a = [1, 2, 3]
res = map(lambda x: x < 2, a)
print(list(res))

# [True, False, False]
```

So for your example:

```py
class TestObj:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

values_list = [10, 1]
objects = [TestObj(ele) for ele in values_list]

res = map(lambda x: x.value > 5, objects)
print(list(res))
```

Or using list comprehension:

```py
res = [obj.value > 5 for obj in objects]
```