# How to get a closure to refer to the value that a variable had at the time of its definition

Tags: python, closures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating lambda inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546285/creating-lambda-inside-a-loop)

In the code below, invoking any member of the returned array of closures
prints the number 4.

```
def go():
    x = []
    for i in range(5):
        def y(): print i
        x.append(y)

    return x
```

I would like each member of the closure to print the number that `i` was when the closure was defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way around this is to use default arguments:

```
def y(i=i): 
    print i
```

Default arguments are evaluated when the function is created, not called, so this works as you'd expect.

```
>>> i = 1
>>> def y(i=i): print i
... 
>>> i = 2
>>> y()
1
```

---

A little extra info just for fun:

If you're curious what the defaults are, you can always inspect that with the `.func_defaults` attribute (`__defaults__` in python3.x):

```
>>> y.func_defaults
(1,)
```

This attribute is also writeable, so you can in fact change the defaults after the function is created by putting a new tuple in there.