# pyqt4 correctly connecting QCheckbox state

Tags: python-2.7, signals, pyqt4, qcheckbox

I have a class `QWidget` class containing a `QLabel`. The class generates `QCheckbox`'es in a `QVBox`. I am trying to connect each checkbox to the method `nameCheckBox` which will update the `QLabel` to display the title of the last checked box. However when a checkbox is effectively un/checked, it is always detected as Unchecked. Also the returned name is always the last created checkbox. I don't understand where my mistake is. Here is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from MenusAndToolbars import MenuWindow

class checkBoxWidget(QWidget):
    """
    This widget has a QVBox which contains a QLabel and QCheckboxes.
    Qcheckbox number is connected to the label.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.__setUI()

    def __setUI(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        label = QLabel('Last clicked button: ' + "None", self)

        vbox.addWidget(label)

        listCB = []

        for i in range(10):
            listCB.append( QCheckBox('CheckBox Nb. ' + str(i+1) ) )
            listCB[i].stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.nameCheckBox(label,  listCB[i]) )
            vbox.addWidget( listCB[i] )


    def nameCheckBox(self, label, checkBox):
        if checkBox.isChecked():
            print "Checked: " + checkBox.text()
            label.setText('Last clicked button: ' + checkBox.text())
        else:
            print "Unchecked: " + checkBox.text()



def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget( checkBoxWidget() )
    window.show()
    #window = WidgetWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

### EDIT 1

I found several "hack" solutions.

SOLUTION 1 : Creating a callBack function does the trick:

```
def callBack(self, list, index, label):
    return lambda: self.nameCheckBox(label, list[index])
```

Then I connect the `QCheckbox().stateChanged` signal this way:

```
listCB[i].stateChanged.connect( self.callBack(listCB, i, label) )
```

SOLUTION 2: using the `partial` module:

First we import the module:

```
from functools import partial
```

Then the signal connection is done this way:

```
listCB[i].stateChanged.connect( partial( self.nameCheckBox, label, listCB[i] ) )
```

However I would like to use lambda expression in one line. Especially I would like to understand how it works. Following links I understood the issue is about lambda scope. As   Oleh Prypin advised me, I wrote:

```
listCB[i].stateChanged.connect(lambda i=i: self.nameCheckBox(label,  listCB[i]) )
```

Here the variable `i` is a new one. However my original issue remains. I then tried this out of curiosity:

```
listCB[i].stateChanged.connect( lambda label=label, listCB=listCB, i=i: self.nameCheckBox(label, listCB[i] ) )
```

But I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Checked: CheckBox Nb. 2
  File "Widgets.py", line 48, in <lambda>
    listCB[i].stateChanged.connect( lambda label=label, listCB=listCB, i=i: self.nameCheckBox(label, listCB[i] ) )
  File "Widgets.py", line 59, in nameCheckBox
    label.setText('Last clicked button: ' + checkBox.text())
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setText'
```

Here it seems the correct button is recognized when un/checked. However it seems the new `label` variable is seen as an int? What happens here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lambda: self.nameCheckBox(label,  listCB[i])
```

binds to the variable `i`, meaning the value of `i` will be the one at the moment the lambda is called, not when it's created, which is, in this case, always 9.
Possible fix:

```
lambda i=i: self.nameCheckBox(label, listCB[i])
```

There is a lot of general information on this topic. Starting points: [Google search](https://google.com/search?q=python+lambda+bind+for+loop), another question [Creating lambda inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546285/creating-lambda-inside-a-loop).

---

Unfortunately, my fix didn't work, because that signal provides an argument `checked` to the function it calls, overriding that default argument with a 0 or 2 depending on the check state. This will work (ignore the unwanted argument):

```
lambda checked, i=i: self.nameCheckBox(label, listCB[i])
```

---

And here is an alternative way to write that class:

```
class CheckBoxWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.label = QLabel("Last clicked button: None")

        vbox.addWidget(self.label)

        for i in range(10):
            cb = QCheckBox("CheckBox Nb. " + str(i+1))
            cb.stateChanged.connect(self.nameCheckBox)
            vbox.addWidget(cb)

    def nameCheckBox(self, checked):
        checkBox = self.sender()
        if checked:
            print("Checked: " + checkBox.text())
            self.label.setText("Last clicked button: " + checkBox.text())
        else:
            print("Unchecked: " + checkBox.text())
```

Comment: Thanks I edited my post with a callback solution and the syntax that i should use like you wrote, however it still does not work, maybe there is also an issue with `listCB`'s scope?

Comment: Thank you very much both methods work like a charm. Being new I tend to forget the `sender()` method which proves to be useful. I guess I systematically have to check values returned by signals in the documentation?

Comment: This (```lambda checked, i=i: self.nameCheckBox(label, listCB[i])```) worked perfectly for me, thank you!