# Final variable in lambda command button - python

Tags: python, lambda

I found some similar questions like these: [Creating lambda inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546285/creating-lambda-inside-a-loop)

But I couldn't figure out how to implement in my case.

Here is the simplified code:

```
i=0
for directory in next(os.walk(_src))[1]:
   Button[i] = Button(frame, text=directory, command= lambda: GotoDir(_src+directory)
   Button[i].grid()
   i=i+1
```

The problem is that I can't fix the variable directory in each button, it all links to the current directory variable value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must change your lambda as follows:

```
command=lambda dir=_src+directory: GotoDir(dir)
```

in order to capture the correct arguments for each lambda function created within the for loop

Comment: Quick and precise, implemented and already working, many thanks!