# Python code is not throwing error but the desired output is not the same

Tags: python-3.x

Unable to receive the output of the python code.I have tried debugging the code by printing each line

```
def get_sum_metrics(predictions, metrics=[]):  
    for i in range(0,3):
        metrics.append(lambda x:x+i)

    sum_metrics = 0
    for metric in metrics:
        sum_metrics += metric(predictions)

    return sum_metrics

def main():
    print(get_sum_metrics(0))
    print(get_sum_metrics(1))
    print(get_sum_metrics(2))
    print(get_sum_metrics(3,[lambda x:x]))
    print(get_sum_metrics(0))
    print(get_sum_metrics(1))
    print(get_sum_metrics(2))


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

expected output should be..
            3
            6
            9
            15
            3
            6
            9

```
        but getting..
        6
        18
        36
        18
        24
        45
        72
```

Answer (score 4):

Your issue here is related to [mutable default arguments](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/) and the problem of creating a `lambda` in a loop as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546285/creating-lambda-inside-a-loop)

Those two things fixed gives you:

```
def get_sum_metrics(predictions, metrics=None):
    if metrics is None:
        metrics = []  
    for i in range(0,3):
        f = lambda x, i=i: x+i
        metrics.append(f)
    sum_metrics = 0
    for metric in metrics:
        sum_metrics += metric(predictions)
    return sum_metrics
```