# debugging python code using pdb in simple way

Tags: python, numpy, debugging, lambda, error-handling

```
def get_sum_metrics(predictions, metrics=[]):
   for i in range(3):
       metrics.append(lambda x: x + i)

   sum_metrics = 0
   for metric in metrics:
       sum_metrics += metric(predictions)

   return sum_metrics
```

The function get_sum_metrics takes two arguments: a prediction and a list of metrics to apply to the prediction (say, for instance, the accuracy or the precision). Note that each metric is a function, not a number. The function should compute each of the metrics for the prediction and sum them. It should also add to this sum three default metrics, in this case, adding 0, 1 or 2 to the prediction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem, another user solved it [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56734903/python-code-is-not-throwing-error-but-the-desired-output-is-not-the-same)

```
def get_sum_metrics(predictions, metrics=None):
  if metrics is None:
     metrics = []  
  for i in range(0,3):
     f = lambda x, i=i: x+i
     metrics.append(f)
  sum_metrics = 0
  for metric in metrics:
     sum_metrics += metric(predictions)
  return sum_metrics
```