# button command problems tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have the following scraper:
I want to do an action to import the links when I click the button that corresponds to each one.

```
def ListarPeliculas(win, canvas, box_formulario, paginacion):
canvas.config(bg='#CCC')
#canvas.pack(side=LEFT, pady=20)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, pady=20)
global scrollbar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(win, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.config(bg='#CCC')
scrollbar.pack(side=LEFT, pady=20, fill=Y)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
def on_configure(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))
canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)
box_formulario.config(bg='#CCC', padx=40)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=box_formulario, anchor='n')

url = 'https://divxtotal7.com/peliculas/page/'+paginacion.get()
header = var.user_agent
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

soup = html.fromstring(r.text)

links_posts = soup.xpath('//ul[@class="miniboxs miniboxs-ficha"]//div[@class="meta"]/a/@href')
titulos_posts = soup.xpath('//ul[@class="miniboxs miniboxs-ficha"]//div[@class="meta"]/a/text()')
idiomas = soup.xpath('//ul[@class="miniboxs miniboxs-ficha"]//div[@class="imagen"]//img[@class="lazy"]/@src')

row = 1
count = 0

for link_post, titulo_post, idioma in zip(links_posts, titulos_posts, idiomas):
    if idioma == '/images/espanolEspañol.png' or idioma == '/images/espanolEspanol.png':
        idioma = 'Español España'
    elif idioma == '/images/espanolVOSE.png':
        idioma = 'Subtitulado a español'
    elif idioma == '/images/espanolEspanol Latino.png':
        idioma = 'Español Latino'
    numero = Label(box_formulario, text=str(row))
    numero.config(bg='#CCC', fg='black', font=('Arial', 10), pady=5)
    numero.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky='nw')
    #name_peliculas = Label(box_formulario, text=titulo_post)
    #name_peliculas.config(bg='#CCC', fg='black', font=('Arial', 8), pady=5)
    #name_peliculas.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='n')
    peliculas_listada = Label(box_formulario, text=link_post, textvariable=link_post)
    peliculas_listada.config(bg='#CCC', fg='black', font=('Arial', 10), pady=5)
    peliculas_listada.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='n', columnspan=2, padx=60)
    idioma_listada = Label(box_formulario, text=idioma)
    idioma_listada.config(bg='#CCC', fg='black', font=('Arial', 10), pady=5)
    idioma_listada.grid(row=row, column=3, sticky='nw')
    importar = Button(box_formulario, text='Importar', command=lambda: [print(link_post)])
    importar.config(bg='orange', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'))
    importar.grid(row=row, column=4, sticky='e', padx=25, pady=5)
    count += 1
    row += 1
```

but when I get the link I get the last link and not what corresponds to each one

What I get every time I click on any button is the following link, the same one and not the one that corresponds to each one

```
https://divxtotal7.com/descargar/43813/padre,-soldado,-hijo/
https://divxtotal7.com/descargar/43813/padre,-soldado,-hijo/
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating lambda inside a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546285/creating-lambda-inside-a-loop)

Comment: can you give me an example with my code?

Comment: Try changing `importar = Button(box_formulario, text='Importar', command=lambda: [print(link_post)])` to `importar = Button(box_formulario, text='Importar', command=lambda link=link_post: print(link))`.

Comment: many thanks! it worked !!!

Answer (score 0):

thanks to the user the solution was this

```
def ListarPeliculas(win, canvas, box_formulario, paginacion):
canvas.config(bg='#CCC')
#canvas.pack(side=LEFT, pady=20)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT, pady=20)
global scrollbar
scrollbar = Scrollbar(win, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.config(bg='#CCC')
scrollbar.pack(side=LEFT, pady=20, fill=Y)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
def on_configure(event):
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all'))
canvas.bind('<Configure>', on_configure)
box_formulario.config(bg='#CCC', padx=40)
canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=box_formulario, anchor='n')

url = 'https://divxtotal7.com/peliculas/page/'+paginacion.get()
header = var.user_agent
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)

soup = html.fromstring(r.text)

links_posts = soup.xpath('//ul[@class="miniboxs miniboxs-ficha"]//div[@class="meta"]/a/@href')
titulos_posts = soup.xpath('//ul[@class="miniboxs miniboxs-ficha"]//div[@class="meta"]/a/text()')
idiomas = soup.xpath('//ul[@class="miniboxs miniboxs-ficha"]//div[@class="imagen"]//img[@class="lazy"]/@src')

row = 1
count = 0

for link_post, titulo_post, idioma in zip(links_posts, titulos_posts, idiomas):
    if idioma == '/images/espanolEspañol.png' or idioma == '/images/espanolEspanol.png':
        idioma = 'Español España'
    elif idioma == '/images/espanolVOSE.png':
        idioma = 'Subtitulado a español'
    elif idioma == '/images/espanolEspanol Latino.png':
        idioma = 'Español Latino'
    numero = Label(box_formulario, text=str(row))
    numero.config(bg='#CCC', fg='black', font=('Arial', 10), pady=5)
    numero.grid(row=row, column=0, sticky='nw')
    #name_peliculas = Label(box_formulario, text=titulo_post)
    #name_peliculas.config(bg='#CCC', fg='black', font=('Arial', 8), pady=5)
    #name_peliculas.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='n')
    peliculas_listada = Label(box_formulario, text=link_post, textvariable=link_post)
    peliculas_listada.config(bg='#CCC', fg='black', font=('Arial', 10), pady=5)
    peliculas_listada.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='n', columnspan=2, padx=60)
    idioma_listada = Label(box_formulario, text=idioma)
    idioma_listada.config(bg='#CCC', fg='black', font=('Arial', 10), pady=5)
    idioma_listada.grid(row=row, column=3, sticky='nw')
    importar = Button(box_formulario, text='Importar', command=lambda link=link_post: print(link))
    importar.config(bg='orange', font=('Arial', 10, 'bold'))
    importar.grid(row=row, column=4, sticky='e', padx=25, pady=5)
    count += 1
    row += 1
```