# tkinter create clickable labels in for loop

Tags: python, tkinter, button, label

I want to create multiple clickable labels in a for-loop. The labels are structured grid-like with a row and col attribute. If I click the label, the row and col of the clicked label should be printed with the print_it() function.
The problem is if I click any label, the output is always the last defined row/col (2,2) in this case. How can I fix it, so the correct row/col gets printed?

Here is a code example to reproduce:

```
from tkinter import *


def print_it(row, col):
    print(row, col)


root = Tk()

sizex = 700
sizey = 400
posx = 0
posy = 0
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

canvas_area = Canvas(root)
canvas_area.grid(row=1, column=1)

labels = []
for row in range(3):
    for col in range(3):
        labels.append(Label(canvas_area, text=f"Row, Col: {row},{col}", bd=0))
        labels[-1].grid(row=row, column=col)

        labels[-1].bind(
            f"<Button-1>",
            lambda e: print_it(row, col),
        )

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

I actually found another post which let me solve this problem: [Python Tkinter: Bind function to list of variables in a for-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172765/python-tkinter-bind-function-to-list-of-variables-in-a-for-loop)
The correct definition of the bind function is this:

```
    labels[-1].bind(
        "<Button-1>",
        lambda event, row=row, col=col: print_it(row, col),
    )
```