# How can I set a 'for loop' generated menu function command to prevent the command reference changing with subsequent loop iterations?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, command

I have used two "for loops" to work through a list of c70 menu items to create a tkinter drop down menu bar. For each `.add_command` iteration, the `for` loop generates the label (`section[i][1]`) and a `command=function` which refers to an argument from the list (`section[i][1]`). However, by the time the menu item is selected and the function called, the function refers for its `section[i][1]` argument to the last list item in the original `for` loop. How can I set the function's argument as the loop generates each menu item, so that it does not change which each loop iteration?

The related code I have used is:

'''

```
from tkinter import Menu

for section in self.master.contents.subsection_list:
    # adds menu category sections
    menu_heading = section[0]
    menu_name = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label=menu_heading, menu=menu_name)
    # adds components of menu category sections
    for i in range(1, len(section)):
        menu_name.add_command(label=section[i][1], command=lambda: print(section[i][1]))
```

'''

In case it is helpful ... each item within the list iterated through by the first "for loop" is structured:

```
[section[0], [section[1][0], section[1][1], section[1][2]], [section[2][0], section[2][1], section[2][2]], ...]
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to capture the lambda-value:  `menu_name.add_command(label=section[i][1], command=lambda captured_i=i: print(section[captured_i][1]))`.. the `lambda captured_i=i: ... ` captures the value of i inside captured_i and uses that. Sometimes you see  `lambda i=i: ... `  wich may be a bit too confusing if you do not know what is going on

Comment: good 1st question btw :)

Comment: .. and one more:  [creating-lambda-inside-a-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546285/creating-lambda-inside-a-loop)

Comment: Hi Patrick. Thank you very much for your answer. That is really helpful. Best wishes.