# I cannot reach Entry's values from tkinter, the last one corrupt others

Tags: python, lambda, tkinter, bind

I am a new Python user. I try to make a serie of entries identified by labels and gets the values inserted. The callback functions seem well done but it's allways the third entry's value which I reach.
I am Python/Linux user, version 2.7.6
It seem to be lambda's declaration issue, can you help me ?

```
import Tkinter as tk
class c1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        r = 0
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.master.title('Test three binds')
        self.master.geometry('300x200+400+400')
        self.ents = {}
        for i in ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'] :
            r += 1
            self.ents[i] = c2()
            self.ents[i].label = tk.Label(text = i)
            self.ents[i].label.grid (row = r, column = 0)
            self.ents[i].entry = tk.Entry()
            self.ents[i].entry.grid (row = r, column = 1)
            self.ents[i].val = tk.StringVar()
            self.ents[i].val.set(i)
            self.ents[i].entry["textvariable"] = self.ents[i].val
            self.ents[i].entry.bind('<Key-Return>', lambda X : self.verif(self.ents[i]))
    def verif(self, event) :
        print event.val.get()

class c2 :
    pass

mm = c1()
for ii in  mm.ents :
    print mm.ents[ii].val.get()

mm.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

One problem is this line of code:

```
self.ents[i].entry["textvariable"] = self.ents[i].val
```

The `textvariable` attribute must be set to an instance of `StringVar` (or one of the other tkinter variables), *not* the value of such an instance. You need to remove `.val`.

The other problem is that you need to bind (as in: create a closure) the value of `i` at the time you create the lambda. You can do that like this:

```
self.ents[i].entry.bind('<Key-Return>', lambda event, i=i : self.verif(self.ents[i]))
```

However, if all you need in `self.verif` is the value from the entry widget, you can reduce the complexity of your code by removing the use of the textvariable altogether, as well as the use of `lambda` since the event contains a reference to the widget itself. Both `textvariables` and `lambda` are rarely truly required.

```
self.ents[i].entry.bind('<Key-Return', self.verif)
...
def  verif(self, event):
    print event.widget.get()
```

On a final note, tkinter `Entry` widgets have built-in verification support. Take a look at this answer for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988/7432

Comment: Thank you for your answer, val is needed to set values of Entrys, your second tip solves the issue : great. I need (I think so) this complication because the c2 instances include more data, not show here, found by 'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc' index. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it comes from a lambda declaration issue.

The `i` in your loop is not actually changing, as [lambdas don't closure the parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7514093/lambda-function-dont-closure-the-parameter-in-python). As such, you can make a simple adjustment to this one line from the `for` loop to remedy this issue:

```
self.ents[i].entry.bind('<Key-Return>', lambda event, i = i: self.verif(self.ents[i]))
```

Changing the lambda to use `i = i` allows you to capture the current value of `i` for each iteration.

Comment: Thank you, it's just what I needed. Great.